# Has North Korea made any statement on the alleged attack on its embassy in Madrid?

Tags: international-relations, north-korea, embassy

According to [the BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-47553804):

> On 22 February, a group of 10 assailants reportedly broke into the building, tying up, beating and interrogating eight people inside.
>
> The incident took place just days before a key summit between US President Donald Trump and North Korean leader Kim Jong-un.
>
> And now there are reports US intelligence services were involved.

Have the North Koreans released any public statement on this alleged attack, for example via international media or via their own state television?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they have described the event as a grave terrorist attack by dissidents.

According to [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/mar/31/grave-terrorist-attack-north-korea-condemns-raid-on-its-madrid-embassy):

> In its first official comment on the raid, North Korea suggested Washington’s 
>   possible involvement and called on Spanish authorities to bring the “terrorists 
>   and their wire-pullers to justice”.
>
> “A grave terrorist attack occurred on February 22, where an armed group 
>   assaulted the DPRK embassy in Spain,” a spokesman for the foreign ministry said 
>   in a statement carried by the official KCNA news agency, using the acronym for 
>   the North’s official name.

The Cheollima Civil Defense has appeared to take credit for the raid.

> Hours after the court statement, the Cheollima Civil Defense (also known as 
>   Free Joseon) – a dissident group believed to include high-profile North Korean 
>   defectors – claimed responsibility for the raid.